# TypeError: "NoneType" object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors

I know that this error message 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable' means that there is None is the data. However, I am looking through all of my list and there is no part which has a no value element. 
This is the section of my code that correlates to my issue.

```
def printList(heights):
    print(" ".join(str(h) for h in heights))


def nextYear(heights):
    next_heights = []
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        next_heights.append(heights[i] + 5)
        i += 1
    print(" ".join(str(h) for h in next_heights))

#main routine

heights = [33, 45, 23, 43, 48, 32, 35, 46, 48, 39, 41]
printList(heights)
print("Predicted heights after a year")
printList(nextYear(heights))
```

This is my codes output:

```
33 45 23 43 48 32 35 46 48 39 41
Predicted heights after a year
38 50 28 48 53 37 40 51 53 44 46
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ellarendell/Desktop/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    printList(nextYear(heights))
  File "/Users/ellarendell/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in printList
    print(" ".join(str(h) for h in heights))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I want my code to do the same output without the error message.
Do you know what part of the list could have 'None'?
Thank you :)

Comment: No, that's telling you that the object you believe is a list, i.e `heights` is actually `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code:

- First you are not returning `next_heights` in your function

```
def nextYear(heights):
    next_heights = []
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        next_heights.append(heights[i] + 5)
        i += 1
    return next_heights
```

Without the return line, it will return `None` and pass it to `printList` function, also you do not need to print inside `nextYear` as you already calling `printList` to print after the function returns the highlights

- Second thing is increasing the iterator, you literally cannot do that, you could try this little example to understand what I mean

```
for i in range(10):
  print(i)
  i +=15555
```

So first thing to do is to remove this line from your loop

```
def nextYear(heights):
    next_heights = []
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        next_heights.append(heights[i] + 5)
    return next_heights
```

It will be incremented automatically every iteration, if you want it to be increased by two instead of one then you can specify that in `range()` function as a step size.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything in the `nextYear` function, which is why the argument `heights` in the `printList` function is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement in `nextYear`.

Your function should be:

```
def nextYear(heights):
    next_heights = []
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        next_heights.append(heights[i] + 5)
        i += 1
    print(" ".join(str(h) for h in next_heights))
    return next_heights
```

... at least from my understanding of what you want `nextYear` to do. In any case, you need a return statement.

My output is:

```
33 45 23 43 48 32 35 46 48 39 41
Predicted heights after a year
38 50 28 48 53 37 40 51 53 44 46
38 50 28 48 53 37 40 51 53 44 46
```

For clarification, the `None` is coming from the return of your `nextYear` function.

In your line `printList(nextYear(heights))`, `nextYear(heights)` returns None, which is passed to `printList`.